# size of objects in python 2.5

Tags: python, python-2.5

In python 2.6 and later you can do `sys.getsizeof`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof("abc")
40
```

Is there a way to do this in python 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

No, no size information is available in Python 2.5 or earlier.

You'd have to backport the (C code) patch from [issue 2898](http://bugs.python.org/issue2898).